What would be the delta in recoil between a firearm and a magnetic gun?
Assumptions
For the purposes of the question, in my world technology has progressed far enough that the power supply problem and the rail/cannon durability issue are solved - all of that is handwaved.
Human civilization has advanced far enough to now have a technologically viable handheld railgun.
Question
For equivalent bullet masses, and achieving equal muzzle velocity, how much of a difference in recoil would there be between a railgun and a conventional firearm?
To simplify among the plethora of options, let's examine the most used caliber worldwide, .38 or 9mm. (I am aware that the same caliber can pack more or less punch.)
Since we don't have a handheld railgun blueprint available, I'm interested in answers dealing with:

The average energy conversion efficiency of modern handguns (specifically, how much in percentage of that goes into accelerating the bullet)1 ?
Which factors that would be considered for a firearm (including but not limited to: barrel friction, projectile motion, hot gases, barrel heat, unburned propellant) can be ignored for a railguns?
(Optional) Which factors that are not relevant to firearms would need to be factored in for railguns ?

At least rough estimates in percentages would be appreciated.
Base principle of the railgun is the one we know of currently.
Preexisting Research
The Internet gives me a ballpark estimate of 30% of the chemical reaction energy in a conventional firearm going into bullet acceleration. My understanding is, while this is what the bullet experiences, the recoil would also be contributed to by part of the wasted energy? Also, this estimate hinges on barrel length, ammunition power, etc. A handgun1 would obviously start at a disadvantage.
We already have a commercially available Gauss Gun (operating on a slightly different principle). We even have test firing videos with people describing the recoil. (Example: Forgotten Weapons). It's not entirely satisfactory, because while this is cool, the GR-1 achieves up to 75 m/s muzzle velocity - while a 10mm auto, which is close in diameter (if not in mass) ranges between 350-490 m/s. Given those figures, it stands to reason the recoil is insignificant. The GR-1 is more of a proof of concept than an actually useful weapon.
Why I am asking
I know that we can achieve significantly higher (>x2) muzzle velocity with a magnetic projectile than we can with a chemically propelled one. But projectile velocity is only one factor in weapon usefulness; if the recoil is not better than in a chemical weapon, then it does not make sense to scale the model to rifle and handgun.
The same thing is true if the energy conversion is so lousy that the barrel needs to be twice as long (though this is off-topic).
As such, this is a good basis to assess if, while the weapon is technologically doable, it is practical and sensible to make them.

For every action there is an equal and opposite reaction. You asked for [tag:science-based]. You can't push a bullet forward if there's nothing to push against, which in this case is your arm. From a practical perspective, the most force you can handle is the greatest force that doesn't pull the gun from your grip. The real question is how much of the forward force actually goes into bullet velocity. One would think a rail gun would be pretty good at that - but even it isn't perfect. Consequence: your hand will always experience more than the bullet.

Yes, Newton's third law did not go take a nap when we invented railgun, I'm well aware, hence the question. (Though I'm glad you confirm in part that recoil experienced is more than the energy imparted to the bullet through losses in the system).
I had actually mentionned Newton in the first draft, then it got lost in 3-5 rewritings.

Also, while there might be a difference between the energy experienced by the bullet and the one experienced by the shooter/weapon duo, I assume some loss factors (Hot gases, Barrel heat, Unburned propellant) are either negligible or do not produce recoil. So energy efficiency is a close enough approximate of the recoil, and we can make it a percentage, which is good for maths (and boy do I love maths).

OK... keep in mind that (a) we're not an engineering stack and (b) you're asking for [tag:science-based] information about magic. But (c) more to the point, there really isn't a difference between traditional firearms and railguns other than the railgun might (might!) be a bit more efficient - maybe. That's the magic problem. If anyone could seriously and accurately answer your question they'd be hauling butt to the patent office and not ansewring it. There might be five scientists on Earth who could challenge these numbers. Why do you need them?

I'm sorry JBH, this is getting personnal, but I have a dislike of the way you equate technology that we did not achieve yet with magic. Clarke is not a universal solution. If you reread the question, I ask specifically data about current firearms to extrapolate the differences and I even posted a current example of a modern day gauss gun that does not run on magic. I argue I specifically phrased this question to focus on technology that we have and science. Not asking someone to sketch me weapons blueprints.

This isn't personal. I'm an engineer and you're asking for specifications to a non-existent technology. Has the US and China tested prototypes? Yes! Are they actively building weapons for their navies? No. What you call a "modern day gauss gun that does not run on magic" it not (yet) a mature technology at all. Therefore, I believe my assertion is sound: you're asking us to extrapolate from an in-development technology to determine if a non-existent technology would have a particular efficiency number. Engineer... no can do... pick a number. It's as good as any other answer.

Oh wow! I'm an engineer too! Nice to meet you :D Anyway, still asking for data about firearms efficiency, as per "Question" part - data I have not been able to locate by myself nor am I versed enough on the topic to figure out by myself.

I think my problem with the question is that you're not asking us to help develop an imaginary technology or a known technology in an imaginary world (where the rules are different from the Real World), you're asking us to extrapolate Real World specifications in the Real World. That's not worldbuilding. Honestly, it's storybuilding in the Real World, which is a world already built. Keep in mind that Stack Exchange is not a free research service.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Consider that a hand-held magnetic gun may behave unpredictability if your soldier is, say, standing next to an iron support beam.  Not exactly recoil, but...

There exist recoilless weapons today, like the Davis machine gun, which fired a lead bullet backwards (against a stop), so you'd spend double the ammo to fire, but with no recoil. A gauss rifle wouldn't need to use extra ammunition if it reset the counterweight projectile after each shot, meaning a recoilless gauss rifle would be much less expensive to fire than a similar recoilless chemical-fired rifle. It would be more complex than a regular rifle, of course, but less challenging to make an "ammo-less" recoilless rifle.

All factors kept constant, the magnetic gun will have lower recoil
When a regular firearm fires, not only does it push the bullet forwards (pushing you backwards), but it also pushes the gases formed by combustion forwards. These gasses have mass, but they don't reach the enemy so you are essentially "paying" the price to accelerate them but they are not contributing to the firearm's effect on target.
A magnetic gun does not have this issue, because it is just accelerating the projectile, and not bringing any extra gasses up to high velocity.
This means that if you control for projectile energy, it will take more energy to bring the firearm-fired bullet to match that of the magnetically fired bullet because part of the momentum is wasted in accelerating gas.
Additionally, there is the secondary effect that, in most firearms, the bullet leaves the barrel when there is still a significant pressure differential before and behind the bullet. Gasses from the combustion are still trying to expand, and as soon as the bullet is no longer blocking the path to "escape", these gasses rapidly exit the barrel producing thrust, like in a rocket.
This is known, and people use "recoil compensators" or "muzzle brakes" which are features of a gun or devices specifically designed to,  redirect this stream of gas upwards in order to push the barrel downwards after firing and counter the effect that recoil usually has: "muzzle climb".
In the image below, you can see how the firearm has a "ported barrel" with holes pointed upwards. As the bullet is leaving the end of the chamber, the combustion gases escape out these holes, and like a bunch of small rocket thrusters, push the barrel downwards to help the user keep the follow-on shot on target.

To illustrate this phenomenon more visually, the graph below shows the force vs the time of a gun firing, along with the effects.

The "Bullet and Gas Recoil" section is the force which "pays" for accelerating the bullet and the gas, while the "jet recoil" section is the part of the recoil caused by the "rocket" or "jet" effect.
More helpfully, the graph also includes the difference between firing with and without a muzzle brake, showing that how recoil is reduced compared to the "brakeless" variant.
A magnetic rifle has none of these problems. It does not (really) accelerate anything extra, has no jet-effect, would not benefit from a muzzle brake, etc. More usefully, the force profile of a magnetic rifle could be digitally tuned, to achieve the same bullet velocity while feeling different to hold.

It is very difficult to express in percentage how much less recoil this would be. A very well designed firearm with a super complicated muzzle brake could theoretically recover essentially all the "wasted" energy, but in practice I doubt it would be feasible to master the fluid dynamics to such a degree.
That said, estimating off the graph:

It might be reasonable to say that anything below the value marked "B" is attributed to "bullet firing" while the area between "A" and "B" is waste, I would ballpark between 5% and 20% less recoil.

Most other answers got this wrong.  "Rocket effect" matters even between different firearms -- with constant bullet momentum, the round/gun that ejects propellant gas at higher velocity will have more recoil.  Simple Newton's Third Law (though it was pretty hard to measure until modern electronics let us do time traces on microsecond resolution, as above).

In short, about twice less recoil due to having no exhaust with the bullet. Nice graphs tho.

I think this is the most detailed one do far. There is another effect not added here though. Linear acceleration vs nonlinear. The gun starts with a big burst, tapering off as the bullet travels down the gun and the gasses lose their pressure on the gun and the bullet. The magnets can be variable, allowing for a linear and hopefully more controlled recoil, giving less physical recoil overall. Or maybe an increasing curve if you want.

@minseong, aren't these gases same - if we consider same caliber bullet and same barrel length?

It seems you glossed over the fact that a muzzle brake can, in principle, reduce the recoil BELOW that what the bullet imparts on the gun because it can use the gasses to counteract it.
A railgun cannot do that (unless it is actually two railguns firing in opposite directions or something like that) so it would probably be better than most real world guns, but worse then a recoil-optimized one.

If I'm reading this graph right, this is the force, and so if we were to integrate it to get impulse, it seems like that'd indicate that the impulse is very much jet-effect dominated. IDK if impulse or peak force is a better proxy for 'how hard to handle' a gun is, though.

Conservation of momentum.
It does not matter how you propel the bullet. The initial momentum of the weapon plus bullet system is zero, and for this reason the final momentum of the weapon plus bullet system must also be zero.
The bullet is very much ligher than the weapon. When the bullet leaves the barrel with a certain muzzle velocity $v_\text{bullet}$, the center of mass of the weapon has to move back with a velocity $$v_\text{weapon} = \frac{m_\text{bullet}}{m_\text{weapon}}v_\text{bullet}$$
Note that when we say that for example 30% of the energy of the propellant goes into accelerating the bullet forwards, this does not mean that the other 70% go into accelerating the weapon backwards. The kinetic energy acquired by the weapon is small. (How small is left as an exercise for the reader.) The bulk of the wasted energy is wasted as heat, not as recoil.
Practical conclusions:

The higher the muzzle velocity, the stronger the recoil.

The heavier the bullet, the stronger the recoil.

The heavier the weapon, the weaker the recoil.


Ideally, to minimize the recoil you want a lighweight bullet fired from a  heavy weapon. But on the other hand, most weapon are carried a hundred thousand times more than they are fired, and heavy weapons are not nice to carry. Hence the need for compromise.

Do I read this correctly? There's no difference between the recoil force of either weapon (conventional firearm vs. railgun) so long as the mass of the weapons and the mass of the bullets and the velocity of the bullets are the same, because however much energy was needed to acclerate the bullet (chemical vs. electric), the losses are (simplistically) just heat? That actually feels correct vs. 35-year-old college classes.

Not entirely correct, because it neglects recoil from propellant gas exiting the barrel.  While it might be theoretically possible to design a barrel-projectile-propellant combination that extracted every iota of kinetic energy from the propellant so that the gas following the projectile was at 1 atm at the muzzle, in practice it's not the case.  It's also worth looking at the practical recoil from the movement of the bolt and (where applicable) gas system to cycle a semi-auto or full-auto - net recoil over a full cycle is zero, but instantaneous recoil is not. (Cont'd)

(Cont'd) How that would change for a gauss weapon would depend on the cycling mechanism for such a weapon but probably a lot less - no need to eject a cartridge case, just move another round into the chamber.

Thanks KerrAvon2055 - My concern is the degree to which the energy that is imparted to the gun (kinetic or otherwise) is greater than the energy imparted to the bullet (because of system loss). Plus the very valid consideration of a (semi-)automatic firearm cycling ammunition, bolt, etc - which I honestly kind of forgot to considerate cause I was focused on the rest.

Don't mean to disparage your answer AlexP, I read when you say that the bulk of waste is thermic - I just wanted to know if the kinetic waste is trivial or not (which if I read you correctly, imply is) and what might add to it specifically in a firearm functionning.

@Nyakouai: The kinetic energy transferred to the weapon increases quadratically with the mass of the projectile and the muzzle speed, and decreases linearly with the mass of the weapon. For a man-portable fire arm it is indeed trivial, on the order of a a few joules; for a cannon it is not trivial at all, although still very small compared to the energy which goes into the projectile. It is just that cannon put a lot of kinetic energy into the projectiles, and even a small fraction of that is a significant amount of energy. Oh, and the energy required to cycle the weapon is always trivial.

The difference between chemical and electromagnetic propellant is that it is much easier to alter the force-over-time curve with a railgun, thus minimizing peak force.

@AlexP "The energy required to cycle the weapon is always trivial" I mean, cycling issue, the need for an adapter to fire blanks - there is a need for a certain amount at least. Though, while cycling uses energy from the recoil (and as such, takes some away from what the user would receive), I feel it's important to mention mostly because of the shift in the center of mass; in most design, that shift will be towards a point behind the gun and above your wrist, which is why your aim bounces and is part of the overall problem of handling recoil.

whilst the total impulse should be equal (neglecting the momentum of exhaust gases), the magnetic gun will spread that impulse relatively equally over the entire period the projectile is in the barrel, whereas with a firearm it is concentrated in the moment the propellant ignites. This means the magnetic gun will have a lower maximum recoil force

While this is correct in the physics sense, it does not answer the question correctly.

Newton's third law of motion, baby!

This does not answer the question "how would recoil differ from firearm to railgun". It only explains why does the recoil exist, also half-heartedly for the firearm part.

@Vesper but it does. The answer is, there is no difference.
Though that neglects the waste energy carried by the gasses that leave the barrel after the bullet, as the accepted answer explains. However a gun can be build in a way that this waste is practically zero (a really good muzzle brake or just make the barrel long enough that there is no overpressure left when the bullet leaves the barrel).

Probably a lot more pleasant to shoot
Felt Recoil (which is realistically what we are talking about here) is a function of 2 main elements:
The Mass of the Projectile
The Mass of the Rifle
Everything else is functionally irrelevant (seriously - look at people shooting blanks - there is virtually no recoil)
My SMLE (which is completely stock, full wood furniture - shooting .303) feels a lot harsher to shoot than my Ruger Precision (which I have tacticooled up with a scope, Rifle sling, Bipod and other gubbins - shooting .308)
Most of that is due to the Ruger weighing an extra Kilo.
Now, if my memory of Physics is correct, the higher the Mass of the Rifle, the longer the recoil impulse is and the more comfortable it is to shoot.
That is to say - for a given cartridge, the amount of energy imparted due to Recoil is the same, but a heavier rifle accelerates slower and has a longer recoil impulse, thus is not short and snappy and painful.
For conventional firearms, as the Bullet travels down the barrel, the rate of acceleration decreases:

You will note that around the 20 inch mark, the acceleration is almost flat (hence why there are very few .308 rifles with a Barrel longer than 20 inches)
With a Rail gun, the acceleration curve could be tuned to be either a straight line, or even an inverse - which would likely have a very real impact on the felt recoil of such a weapon. With the right gubbins, this could even be tuned to a shooters preference. Someone more familiar with conventional firearms might want a similar acceleration (and therefore recoil impulse) as above. Someone not used to conventional firearms, might want a flatter line.

(a) Simplistically, the greater the ratio of the mass of the rifle to the mass of the round.... It's not quite that simple as the force to accelerate a bullet matters. Guns shooting blanks have no recoil because nothing's holding back the energy. Increase the energy or the bullet mass and you need more rifle mass to compensate. (b) This doesn't answer the OP's question (but it was an interesting read).

@JBH - I am reading the difference in recoil to be difference in felt recoil - which IMO, a Railgun would probably feel less snappy and more comfortable to shoot if it had a linear acceleration curve

I don't disagree with you other than to point out that the length of that curve (in either case) is measured in at best milliseconds. Yes, that does make a difference, but the energy must still be absorbed. However, my read on the question is that the OP is asking about handguns, which are a lot less sensitive to this issue than long guns. (I'm not the down vote, btw.)

@JBH - IIRC, Handguns are more sensitive to this issue, since they have shorter barrels, Handgun powder has a higher peak pressure as they have less distance to accelerate the bullet in - so have a much more peaky acceleration Curve.

That wouldn't surprise me! But another issue, one that lends well to your answer, is that the "felt recoil" of the hand (aka wrist and fingers and all other things being equal) is much greater than in the shoulder. All this is of value to the OP, who I suspect will be basically disappointed that there isn't a simple, single number to represent the answer sought. I seem to recall having read a treatise once on the difference measuring recoil between hand guns and long guns and this is one of my memories.

@TheDemonLord handguns are more sensitive to this issue, but "hand-rail-guns" also have much less barrel length to spread the acceleration over. So the idea of "flattening the acceleration curve" is much more useful in railguns with a longer barrel.

Many modern rifles designed for accuracy have free-floating barrels, which are not in physical contact with the stock, meaning the impulse to the barrel is not necessarily instantaneously transmitted to the stock and (though it) the operator of the rifle. There are even two rifles that exploit this to the point of firing a burst that leaves the barrel before significant recoil is felt (the AN-94 and G11) at the cost of high complexity, but it is relatively much simpler to mechanically alter the felt recoil profile.

@JBH I think the recoil curve being milliseconds can make all the difference. The bullet impact energy is slightly lower than the recoil of the gun, and yet the result is catastrophic on the impact side and not the recoil side. All thanks to the bullet having a fraction of the surface area. The start of the curve is but a fraction of the milliseconds. A flat  recoil 'curve' over such a relatively much larger time could make a huge difference.

@timuzhti - That is not how a Free floated barrel works. It has nothing to do with recoil and everything to do with not interfering with Barrel harmonics. What you are thinking of is that most of the felt recoil is imparted to the shooter when the Bolt Carrier Group hits the end of its travel. If you can fire a second round before the bolt carrier group reaches the end of its travel, the second shot will exit the barrel before the recoil is felt by the shooter.

@TheDemonLord, the point is that whatever part that is is not directly in contact with the shooter, and does not transmit any impulse instantaneously.

If you can explain more about how "felt recoil" works I'd be really interested. Is there a unit of 'felt recoil' that people use to compare guns? How would you measure it other than "ooh, that's about a 6/10"

@timuzhti - I can assure you, a free floated barrel is in direct contact with the shooter...

@Kaia - there's probably some maths one could do, but the problem is that alot of it is down to the Shooter - a 6 ft 6 dude who is built like a tank will experience recoil differently than a 5 ft nothing 40 kg lady. Then there is experience. Plenty of petite ladies with a lot of trigger time can handle recoil better than a noob guy who has never shot in his life.

The difference is likely to be negligible for any reasonably sized gun assuming the magnetic gun is also designed for proper recoil damping.
Put simply, conservation of momentum means that the net momentum of the gun plus bullet has to be the same both before the bullet is fired and after it leaves the muzzle. If we ignore the propellant (I’ll cover this in a moment) and ignore recoil damping provided by the cycling of a typical semi-automatic or automatic firearm (I’ll also cover this in a moment), then the backwards velocity of the gun will be directly proportionate to the ratio of the mass of the bullet to the mass of the gun. This is true regardless of the technology used to accelerate the bullet (though it gets a bit more complicated for systems where the bullet is the source of it’s own acceleration, like with an RPG or old Gyrojet guns).
There are two major complications here though:

In firearms, the propellant is part of the mass of the initial system, so the expulsion of the combustion products of the propellant down the barrel (or out of vents) also impacts the velocity of the gun itself. The mass involved here is minuscule though (for comparison, a typical 9x19mm cartridge has about 0.30-0.35g of propellant, while the bullet in such a cartridge typically has a mass of about 4-8g and a fully loaded full-size 9x19mm handgun can easily have a mass of almost a kilogram), so it has a negligible impact on the actual velocity of the gun. This quite simply won’t be a factor at all though for a magnetic gun, which is ever so slightly in favor of a magnetic gun.

Essentially all modern automatic and semi-automatic light arms use feed mechanisms that are powered either by the expansion of the combustion gasses (gas operated) or by the backwards force on the back of the chamber (blowback or recoil operated). IOW, the energy that would go in to accelerating the gun backwards goes at least partly into instead accelerating a smaller part of the gun backwards to compress a spring, and the motion of that part compressing the spring and then being moved back into place by the spring is what clears the empty casing from the chamber and loads a new round into the chamber. This actually eats a lot of energy that would otherwise push the whole gun backwards, and if done right can actually almost completely eliminate felt recoil, with the KRISS Vector being a particularly famous example of this (a 9x19mm KRISS Vector feels about like a heavy .22 LR handgun in terms of recoil when fired, and the .45 ACP KRISS Vector feels about like a heavy 9x19mm carbine when fired).
It’s possible that a magnetic gun could be designed to operate in a similar manner, though it would be rather challenging to achieve. You would essentially need the rails to be floating so that they would get pushed backwards as they push the bullet forwards, but the mechanical design requirements to pull that off would both make the gun much much bigger, and also significantly increase the overall complexity. Without this you lose out on the energy recapture aspect of the feed mechanisms used in most modern firearms, and thus would need the gun to be much heavier to achieve an equivalent amount of damping of felt recoil.



How would you actually dampen recoil on a railgun? You don't have another mass to give impulse to, other than the railgun projectile.

@Vesper If the whole rail assembly can slide independently of the receiver, you can spring-load it just like the bolt of a semi-automatic rifle or the slide of a semi-automatic handgun, and could probably even make it power the loading mechanism in a similar way. The rails need to be easily replaceable anyway since they’re the principle wear component in a railgun. The tricky part is cleanly powering them in such a setup and sizing the spring correctly, plus the mechanical complexity of keeping them in alignment in spite of this.

Well, springing up the railgun assembly would only prolong recoil length, but it won't remove the need to absorb the impulse. Firearms use muzzle brakes to lessen the need of absorbing the shock after firing, but these work only because there is some gas to throw backwards, while here with a railgun you have none. Applying less recoil force for longer would help the gunner to stabilize his targetting, yet the momentum would still have to be transferred off the gun to the support.

@Vesper Firearms mostly use the mass of the gun to compensate for recoil (if you don’t believe me, go compare a Glock 17 to a Glock 43, they use the same cartridge and an identical chamber and feed mechanism, but the 43 has far more recoil because it’s far lighter), muzzle brakes tend to only be used on lighter guns that use cartridges with a particularly high bolt thrust proportionate to their size. And shifting the momentum to be lower force over a longer time reduces the acceleration required to dump the energy involved, which is a large part of what is required to make a gun safe to fire.

The answers above neglect the momentum of the ejected propellant gas. For the railgun, there is none, but for a firearm, there is plenty. It's difficult to calculate precisely. Some firearms and cannons use muzzle brakes to capture some of that momentum. That these usefully reduce recoil but do not eliminate it suggests that the recoil from the gas is modestly less than the recoil from the projectile.

It is not so much neglect as when you shoot blanks - there is virtually no recoil.

This answer is pretty much obsolete, although it does display the other answers' problems. The answer by Dragongeek encompasses this one.

@TheDemonLord Do blanks use less gunpowder than normal cartridge?

@Questor - it depends - but usually yes - however, even with a full powder charge, the mass of gass expelled is very small.

"For equivalent bullet masses, and achieving equal muzzle velocity, how much of a difference in recoil would there be between a railgun and a conventional firearm?" The railgun would experience significantly less recoil because there is far less wasted energy involved in getting the mass of the bullet to the desired muzzle velocity. The details are explained very well in other answers so I won't repeat them, but it should be noted that a railgun is not a different type of gunpowder, and so it can not fire a traditional lead bullet, nor is it restricted by the physics that dictate traditional muzzle velocities. Instead, it is an electro-magnetic accelerator that requires access to a significant energy resource, making it near useless for a handgun applications. It would be possible to use in a rifle type application but I would suggest the minimum viable application it would be closer to a Barrett M50 than a Winchester repeater so possibly man portable (just about) but most likely a squad or fixed based weapon, rendering recoil irrelevant.

Hey Paul. The question states: "power supply problem [.....] is handwaved."

@Escapeddentalpatient. - Question also states "Human civilization has advanced far enough to now have a technologically viable handheld railgun." making the rest of the question meaningless. Railguns are not an improved gunpowder so gunpowder technologies do not apply to railguns.

You're telling me! The comments in chat have been trying to clear the question's issues up for a while - but it remains.

Technologically viable is not the same as having any actual use. The premise is that, in setting, it can be done- the question is used to know if it would make sense to actually be done. If you can make a gun you can not shoot, then you are not going to sell a lot of those guns (or see people use them). And it's precisely because "railguns are not an improved gunpowder" and technology are different that this is a non-trivial question - end purpose of both tech is the same, implementation is different. For more infos, chat has been spawned. Hope it helps.

@Nyakouai - the existence of the Desert Eagle and similar class weapons is sufficient proof that "making sense" is not a significant motivator. It has already been pointed out numerous times that the efficiency of a electromagnetic acceleration means the same kinetic energy can be achieved with far less recoil.
